# How to create resource dictionary files like MahApps.Metro?

Tags: wpf, styles

In [MahApps.Metro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro), the file organization like this:

[image]

but my try like this:

[image]

Who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just from adding a `DependentUpon` attribute linking the children to the parent file.

MahApps.Metro.csproj has something like:

```
<Page Include="Styles\Controls.ComboBox.xaml">
  ...
  <DependentUpon>Controls.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Page>
```

You can do this pretty easily via an Addin for VisualStudio - [NestIn](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9d6ef0ce-2bef-4a82-9a84-7718caa5bb45).

You can then select multiple files -> right click -> choose `Nest Item` -> select the parent and you should have the back-end *.csproj edited accordingly for your selected collection.

A detailed description to do it manually can be found [here](http://davefancher.com/2012/02/23/nesting-files-in-visual-studio/).

Comment: Oh, I nest two file, but in .csproj there is not  `<DependentUpon>Controls.xaml</DependentUpon>`. If I add this, the files organization was not changed.

Comment: @SubmarineX so what is it like? I don't follow your comment. Are you using the Addin or doing it manually?

Comment: @SubmarineX make sure to hit the "Save All" or press ctrl+shift+s. .csproj files aren't saved instantly. Once you do the nesting with the addin try closing the solution and it will tell you "do you want to save the changes made to sln"

Comment: NestIn works finely. I just try to achieve it manually, now it's OK. Maybe just now I have not save the project, so that .csproj is not be changed. Thank you again!